# Run a SQL script in spring-test root startup

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-test

I have a spring project, and I am doing unit testing of my project with spring-test in a PostgreSQL database for the test (I have a database for test and another for development). And I want to initialize my database with a SQL script in the startup (root) of all tests.

I need some direction, I found "flyway" but first I am looking for something with basic spring or something like that or any idea. Thanks

Comment: Check `@Sql` annotation : https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#__sql

Comment: thank you for your comment. I checked the link. Me I need to run the script one time for all the tests, in the startup

Answer (score 0):

To initialize an existing (i.e., normally _external) database when the Spring `ApplicationContext` starts, you can either use the `jbbc` namespace in XML or a `DataSourceInitializer` with JavaConfig.

See [Initializing a database using Spring XML](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-initializing-datasource) and [DataSourceInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/DataSourceInitializer.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

there is simple implementation from spring side 
all we need is just add line below

> ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection, new
>   ClassPathResource("DB_structures_Creation.sql"));

This implementation by default will uses H2 and will create all the tables and other stuff except pl-sql ones